# When passing a Rust pointer to C should I get 0x1?

Tags: c, rust, ffi

I'm trying to implement a basic library in Rust that creates an object and returns its pointer to C. The pointer I get doesn't look like it is on the heap — when I print it I get `0x1`:

```
use std::fmt;

pub struct SndbDB {}

impl SndbDB {
    fn new() -> SndbDB {
        SndbDB {}
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for SndbDB {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "(sndb_db)")
    }
}

// Implement a destructor just so we can see when the object is destroyed.
impl Drop for SndbDB {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("[rust] dropping {}", self);
    }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn sndb_db_create() -> *mut SndbDB {
    let _db = Box::into_raw(Box::new(SndbDB::new()));
    println!("[rust] creating DB {:?}", _db);
    _db
}

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn sndb_db_destroy(ptr: *mut SndbDB) {
    println!("[rust] destroying DB {:?}", ptr);
    Box::from_raw(ptr); // Rust drops this for us.
}
```

The C calling code is trivial too:

```c
typedef struct sndb_db sndb_db;

sndb_db * sndb_db_create(void);
void sndb_db_destroy(sndb_db* db);

void test_baseapi__create_and_destroy_db(void)
{
    sndb_db * db = sndb_db_create();
    printf("[C] Got db=%p\n",db);
    sndb_db_destroy(db);
    printf("[C] db should be dead by now...\n");
}
```

And all the output except the pointer location are as I expect:

```
[rust] creating DB 0x1
[C] Got db=0x1
[rust] destroying DB 0x1
[rust] dropping (sndb_db)
[C] db should be dead by now...
```

I know that memory allocated in Rust needs to be deallocated by Rust - but I'm still surprised it is using a location of `0x1` - am I doing something wrong, is something odd happening, or is this all OK?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like this is an optimisation by Rust since the `SndbDB` struct has no state.

Adding an `i: u32` field to it and plumbing that through to the constructor functions and the C code I then get:

```
[rust] creating DB 0x7fff2fe00000
[C] Got db=0x7fff2fe00000
[rust] destroying DB 0x7fff2fe00000
[rust] dropping (sndb_db i=123)
[C] db should be dead by now...
```

However I'd still love to find an official source to back up this guess.

Comment: Rust avoids ever *actually* allocating memory for zero-sized types.  Instead, it uses a "placeholder" pointer value.  That's what's happening here.  Something similar happens with `Vec`: if you have a vector of zero-sized values, it never bothers to allocate any memory and just tracks how many elements you've pushed.

Comment: @DK that is what I guessed must be happening (though after much hair pulling). Do you have some official docs or other sources to back this up? ( even a reference to  "the source" would be great). C and C++ avoid doing this since they want the dev to be able to distinguish such objects.

Comment: I don't think this is documented anywhere because it's an implementation detail.  There's [`EMPTY`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/b6f554b6dc972608761db93a375bcb0e89155e1d/src/liballoc/heap.rs#L231-L237) and, more recently, [`Unique::empty`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.19.0/src/core/ptr.rs.html#1011).  Using the memory allocator for unique IDs is pretty janky, given the overhead involved.

Comment: Structs of zero size is a Rust feature and it is not supported in C. Only opaque use of such types (behind a pointer) are possible with ffi to C for this reason.

Comment: In https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ptr/#safety there is some language about zero-sized pointer accesses. It says "[C]asting any non-zero integer literal to a pointer is valid for zero-sized accesses, even if some memory happens to exist at that address and gets deallocated. This corresponds to writing your own allocator: allocating zero-sized objects is not very hard. The canonical way to obtain a pointer that is valid for zero-sized accesses is NonNull::dangling."